# How to call a method through the object created by interface in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I need to call a method through the object created by the interface ie

```
id<MyProtocol>obj;
```

Now i have created this obj in my main class where i am not implementing the methods of this protocol but i need to access the method which is already implemented in someother class.I am now calling the method as follows

```
[obj load];
```

in my main class in the applicationDidFinishLaunching, but i not able to access the method?
Pls do suggest me the correct way of calling the methods through protocols...

Answer (score 2):

A protocol implements nothing. It only describes a set of messages that the object should respond to. Your `obj` object belongs to some class. This class needs to implement methods described in `MyProtocol`.

#### Edit

A protocol is not implemented by a specific class. Any class that claims to conform to a protocol must implement its methods. Any object that claims to conform to a protocol must belong to a class that implements its methods.

In your case, `obj` is a `ClassB`, so `ClassB` must implement methods described by `MyProtocol`, either directly or through inheritance.

Comment: MyProtocol is already taken by a class say ClassA and implemented with the method.Now i need to call the method through the object created by MyProtocol ie obj in ClassB. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

`[obj load]` is OK. If you want to shut up the compiler you can cast it to `id`:

```
[(id)obj load];
```

But if you know you'll need to call the `-load` method, maybe you should add the `-load` method to the protocol, or make another protocol that has the `-load` method e.g.

```
@protocol Loadable
-(void)load;
@end

...
id<MyProtocol, Loadable> obj;
```

Comment: MyProtocol is already taken by a class say ClassA and implemented with the method.Now i need to call the method ie load method through the object created by MyProtocol ie obj in ClassB. How do i do that?